# WNetUseConnection SystemErrorCode 1113 No Mapping Exist

Tags: c++, winapi, unc

I am trying to convert a string into a wchar_t string to use it in a WNetUseConnection function.
Basicly its an unc name looking like this `"\\remoteserver"`.
I get a **return code 1113**, which is described as:

> No mapping for the Unicode character
>   exists in the target multi-byte code
>   page.

My code looks like this:

```
 std::string serverName = "\\uncDrive";
 wchar_t *remoteName = new wchar_t[ serverName.size() ];
 MultiByteToWideChar(CP_ACP, 0, serverName.c_str(), serverName.size(), remoteName, serverName.size()); //also doesn't work if CP_UTF8

 NETRESOURCE nr;
 memset( &nr, 0, sizeof( nr ));
 nr.dwType = RESOURCETYPE_DISK;
 nr.lpRemoteName = remoteName;

 wchar_t pswd[] = L"user"; //would have the same problem if converted and not set
 wchar_t usrnm[] = L"pwd"; //would have the same problem if converted and not set
 int ret = WNetUseConnection(NULL,  &nr, pswd, usrnm, 0, NULL, NULL, NULL);      
 std::cerr << ret << std::endl;
```

The intersting thing is, that if remoteName is hard codede like this:

```
char_t remoteName[] = L"\\\\uncName";
```

Everything works fine. But since later on the server, user and pwd will be parameters which i get as strings, i need a way to convert them (also tried mbstowcs function with the same result).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MultiByteToWideChar will not 0-terminate the converted string with your current code, and therefore you get garbage characters following the converted "\uncDrive"

Use this:

```
std::string serverName = "\\uncDrive";
int CharsNeeded = MultiByteToWideChar(CP_ACP, 0, serverName.c_str(), serverName.size() + 1, 0, 0);
wchar_t *remoteName = new wchar_t[ CharsNeeded ];
MultiByteToWideChar(CP_ACP, 0, serverName.c_str(), serverName.size() + 1, remoteName, CharsNeeded);
```

This first checks with MultiByteToWideChar how many chars are needed to store the specified string *and* the 0-termination, then allocates the string and converts it. Note that I didn't compile/test this code, beware of typos.